# SQLAlchemy: get the object with the most recent date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I query a table for the object with the most recent table?

I've got a table which holds

```
class Ticker(Base):
    updated = Column('updated', DATETIME, index=False, nullable=False,primary_key=True)
    high = Column('high', FLOAT, index=False, nullable=False)
```

I'm trying to find out how I can get the object with the most recent updated field? Currently I'm doing the following:

```
maxdate = db_session.query(func.max(Ticker.updated)).first()[0]
Ticker.query.filter(Ticker.updated == maxdate).first()
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient/shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to [order by](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by) `updated` and [limit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit) to one result. This should work(I haven't tested it, syntax might be wrong) -

```
Ticker.query.order_by('updated desc').limit(1)
```

Answer (score 22):

for version 1.2+:

```
session.query(Ticker).order_by(desc('updated')).first()
```

[desc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc)

Answer (score 1):

Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20938298/2780179) with a small variation in syntax:

```
session.query(Ticker).order_by(Ticker.updated.desc()).limit(1)
```